bound for an integral that can be expressed as an hypergeometric function
Let $0<a,b<1$, $h <1$. I'm trying to prove the bound
$$
I(h)=h^a\int_0^t \dfrac{(s+h)^{(1-a)}}{(t-s)^b} ds \lesssim h^{a-\epsilon}
$$
for each $\epsilon>0$
When $a\to 0$ we have
$$
\int_0^t \dfrac{(s+h)}{(t-s)^b} ds=h \dfrac{t^{1-b}}{1-b}+\dfrac{t^{2-b}}{(1-b)(2-b)}
$$
and so, for $a$ small enough we have  $I(h) \lesssim h^a$.
Similarly for $a \to 1$ we have
$$
\lim_{a \to 1} \int_0^t \dfrac{(s+h)^{(1-a)}}{(t-s)^b} ds= \dfrac{t^{1-b}}{1-b}
$$
and so $I(h) \lesssim h^a$
Moreover for $h \to 0$ we get ( by the monotone convergence theorem)
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\int_0^t \dfrac{(s+h)^{(1-a)}}{(t-s)^b} ds=\dfrac{\Gamma(2-a)\Gamma(1-b)}{\Gamma(3-a-b)}
$$
and so for $h$ small enough $I(h) \lesssim h^a$
The integral can be expressed in term of an hypergeometric function indeed we have
$$
\int_0^t \dfrac{(s+h)^{(1-a)}}{(t-s)^b} ds= \dfrac{h^{1-a} t^{1-b}}{1-b} \ _2F_1(1,-(1-a);2-b;-t/h)
$$
Is there a way to bound the integral in terms of power of $h$?

Is the following bound satisfying: $I(h)\leq h^{\alpha}\int_0^t\frac{(t+1)^{1-a}}{(t-s)^{b}}ds=h^{\alpha}\frac{(t+1)^{1-a}t^{1+b}}{1+b}=\mathcal{O}(h^{\alpha}).$
